# How to output the very first rolling average in a rolling average program?

Tags: c, moving-average

So say I'm given a list of numbers: 8,4,5,3,2,1.
The rolling average of this list would be: 8, 6, 5.7, 5, 4.4, 3.8.

My program uses this algorithm :
new average = (((old average * the first iteration) + the next number / (the next iteration)).

The problem is: my program outputs all the running averages EXCEPT for the very first one (which is technically just the first number, because a number divided by 1 is that number). It also outputs a random number at the very end. How can I fix my algorithm to incorporate the very first average with all the other running averages? side note: in the algorithm, the very first "old average" is the first number itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i,n, input_cases, x;
    double numbers[100]; double previous[100];
    double mean[100]; double old_average[100]; double new_average[100];
    double *results = malloc(input_cases*sizeof(double));

    printf("Total amount of numbers: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {  /* validates input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
        for (i=0; i<n; i++){
            scanf("%lf", &numbers[i]);
            }
            old_average[0] = numbers[0];
        for (i=0; i<n; i++){

            new_average[i] = (((old_average[i] * (i+1)) + numbers[i+1]) / (i+2));
            old_average[i+1]=new_average[i];
            printf("%lf\n", new_average[i]);
        }


    return 0;
}
```

This is what my program inputs/outputs using the example above:

```
Input:
8
4
5
3
2
1
Output:
6.0 (This is the SECOND running average, not the first)
5.666667
5.000000
4.400000
3.830000
3.2857514 (This is the random number that doesn't belong)
```

Comment: Try printing old_average instead of new_average...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version that should do what you want.  It uses a running sum rather than the previous average, eliminating the need to keep multiplying and dividing, so the result will be more accurate:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, n;
    double numbers[100];
    double sum, avg;

    printf("Total amount of numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {  /* validates input */
        fprintf(stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        scanf("%lf", &numbers[i]);
    }

    sum = 0.0;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        sum += numbers[i];
        avg = sum / (i+1);
        printf("%lf\n", avg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow. i've been trying to figure this out for so long. thank you so much

Comment: Correct answer. The only way you can compute using the running average is to multiply it up to get the running sum, so it's more accurate to keep tthe sum in the first place. What OP did is more like a *filter*.

Comment: can you help me expand my program?

Comment: The original code works fine if you print old_average and not new_average each time...

Comment: @cleblanc As explained, it had accuracy problems and was unnecessarily convoluted. You never want to have to keep rescaling the way it did, which will result in cumulative inaccuracies.

Comment: @TomKarzes hey tom, i greatly appreciate you fixing my issue. Now that I have all the correct running averages, how would I go about outputting the highest one out of all of them? Should I run a loop where each running average is compared to one another?

Comment: @user5983028 Just add a new scalar variable, `max_avg`.  Initialize it to `numbers[0]`, then each time through the loop compare it to `avg`, and if `avg` is greater, set `max_avg = avg`.  At the end of the loop, `max_avg` will be the largest of the rolling averages.

Comment: @TomKarzes like this? 

for (i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(max_avg<avg){
                max_avg=avg;
            }

Comment: @user5983028 Right, although you don't need a separate loop, you can put it inside the same loop that computes the averages, right below the line that assigns to `avg`.  And don't forget to initialize it before the loop.

Comment: is this the right way to initialize it?

double max_avg=numbers[0];  

I ran it through the loop but it wasn't giving me the highest number

Comment: How can I go about showing you my code without asking another question on this website? You have helped me a lot and I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me finish up my program

Comment: @user5983028 (1) Right before the loop, insert `max_avg = numbers[0];` (2) Inside the loop, right below the line that assigns to `avg`, insert `if (max_avg < avg) max_avg = avg;`

Comment: @TomKarzes hey tom, So i added in the code you told me to and it works. but now i want to output the two highest rolling averages of two different list of numbers. I want to output them all at the end at the same time. I have created a dynamically allocated array to store the two highest running averages in but It wont show properly.

Comment: @user5983028 I think we're well beyond the scope of the original post at this point.  If my answer solved your problem, then please accept it.  If you have a further question, and you can't solve it on your own, then you can post it as a new topic.

Comment: will do @TomKarzes, watch out for my next question